# Where is the JDK version to be used by Maven compiler specified?

Tags: maven, maven-3, java

When I do not define something as follows in my pom.xml file, where on my system is it defined for Maven which version of Java JDK to use while compiling (I have several versions installed on my system, `JAVA_HOME` points to one of them)?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I still see an issue with the proposed solutions. As in ,my use case, I have JDk1.8 installed and clone a GIT repository that I (well feel) should not change the maven-compiler-plugin settings. I have configured a <profile> with both 1.7 and 1.8 JDKs. How can I inform maven to use on or the other without changing the source provided?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maven doc says

> The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of your project. The default compiler is javac and is used to compile Java sources. Also note that **at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven with.** If you want to change these defaults, you should set source and target as described in Setting the `-source` and `-target` of the Java Compiler.

ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html

There is this interesting thread on Maven's Jira [Change default source level to 1.5](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-80)

---

**EDIT:**
Update for Maven 3.0 and later:

> The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of your project. *Since 3.0, the default compiler is javax.tools.JavaCompiler* (if you are using java 1.6) and is used to compile Java sources. If you want to force the plugin using javac, you must configure the plugin option forceJavacCompilerUse.

Source: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html

Thanks [nachteil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2829378/nachteil) for pointing it out.

Comment: Since version 3.0 this is not true - see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

simply use properties

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

From maven compiler plugin doucemntation:

> Since 3.0, the default compiler is javax.tools.JavaCompiler (if you are using java 1.6) and is used to compile Java sources. If you want to force the plugin using javac, you must configure the plugin option forceJavacCompilerUse.

I found this post via search engine and I think it is worth updating. 
Also: the `-target` and `-source` options do not affect the compiler itself, but rather the way it handles source code and produces output byte code.

Answer (score 1):

You must define a property in  your maven setting.xml file. The property is your second javac path.(D:\dev\java\ibm\java1.6.0\bin\javac)After use this property for  maven-compiler-plugin in your pom file.

*setting.xml*

```
 <settings>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>IBM_JAVA</id>
            <properties>
              <IBM_JAVA_1_6_JAVAC>D:\dev\java\ibm\java1.6.0\bin\javac</IBM_JAVA_1_6_JAVAC>
            </properties>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>     
        <activeProfile>IBM_JAVA</activeProfile>   
    </activeProfiles>
    </settings>
```

*pom.xml*

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>${IBM_JAVA_1_6_JAVAC}</executable>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```