# Force Maven to use System's javac

Tags: maven, javac

I have made some code changes to javac and would like maven to use the version of javac that I changed. Unfortunately, it appears that maven ships its own javac implementation. How can I get maven to compile sources using the system wide javac (the one that is executed when running `javac` in the shell).

Without really knowing what these options mean, I tried providing the `fork`, and `forceJavacCompilerUse` which I found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html
But they do not appear to help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right ballpark. Look here:

> http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html
>
> To avoid hard-coding a filesystem path for the executable, you can use
>   a property. For example:
>
> `<executable>${JAVA_1_4_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>`
>
> Each developer then defines this property in settings.xml, or sets an
>   environment variable, so that the build remains portable.

```
<settings>   
    [...]   
  <profiles>
    [...]
    <profile>
      <id>compiler</id>
        <properties>
          <JAVA_1_4_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\j2sdk1.4.2_09</JAVA_1_4_HOME>
        </properties>
    </profile>   
  </profiles>   
  [...] 
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>compiler</activeProfile>   
  </activeProfiles> 
</settings>
```

> If you build with a different JDK, you may want to customize the jar
>   file manifest.

I believe the key is setting an explicit `<executable>`.  And I suspect it can probably be hard-coded, without messing with environment variables or other clauses.

See also this link, and look at the "executable" in the sample `pom.xml`:

[Where is the JDK version to be used by Maven compiler specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603591/where-is-the-jdk-version-to-be-used-by-maven-compiler-specified)

Comment: About the last part of the answer: I went to the Manifest Customization page of maven-jar-plugin via the link, but the word executable is not present in the example pom.xml there. I also went to some time travelling via web.archive.org, but looking back as far as the 2009 versions of this page, I found no trace of "executable" in the sample pom.xml there. Ami I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe maven looks for JVA_HOME for finding the java. So when you set it to your specific java maven should be able to use it